# ajax загрузка изображений

Tags: php, jquery

Помогите найти ошибку в обработчики поступивших фалов на сервер.

Сервер ничего не возвращает, когда стоит проверка `isset( $_FILES['files'] )`, но если ставить `isset( $_FILES )`, то он начинает хоть что-то возвращать.

Форма:

```
<input title="Выберите файл для загрузки" id="upload_media" type="file" name="files" accept=".txt,image/*">
```

Обработчик:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    Upload.files = this.files[0];
    var upload = Upload.upload();
});

var Upload = {
files: 0,
upload: function() {

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each( Upload.files, function( key, value ){
        data.append( key, value );
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function( reply ){
            alert( "test. " + reply );
        },
        error: function( reply ){
            console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + reply.responseText );
        }
    });
},
}
```

Сервер:

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['files'] ) ) {
    $error = false;
    $status = false;
    $files = [];

    $uploaddir = './uploads/';
    $files = $_FILES;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($files['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file( $files['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) ) {
        echo "Файл загружен";
    } else {
        echo "Ошибка";
    }

    echo json_encode( $files['name'] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isset( $_FILES['files'])` не работает, насколько я знаю

Попробуйте поставить такое условие:

```
if ($_FILES['files']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK and $_FILES['files']['size'] != 0) {
    // загрузка прошла успешно
}else{
    // загрузка не удалась
}
```

Comment: Возвращает `Undefined index: files`

Comment: `if (isset($_FILES['files']['name'])` думаю достаточно даже этой проверки, попробуйте

Comment: теперь возвращает просто слово "Ошибка".
Код:
`if ( isset( $_FILES['files']['name'] ) ) { echo "Файл загружен"; } else { echo "Ошибка"; } `

Comment: я нашел ошибку, спасибо.

Comment: сразу и не посмотрел на js, а для отправки данных формы с использованием FormData вроде как нужно использовать XMLHttpRequest: `xhr.open("POST", "upload.php");` где нашли ошибку всё таки?

Comment: В формировании объекта data, переписал на `var data = new FormData(); data.append("files", Upload.files)`